# Retrieving a list of entites based on an array of ids

Tags: java, jpa, criteriaquery

I have an array of ids, long[] ids, and I want to retrieve a List of entities that have the ids from the id array using CriteriaQuery.

I tried to achieve this with the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < orderIds.length; i++) { 
    criteriaQuery.select(root); 
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(path,orderIds[i]));
    List<E>certificates=super.entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    map.put(orderIds[i], certificates); 
}
```

This code returns a Map, but I want to retrieve a list of all the entities E that have the ids among the `orderIds` list. How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < orderIds.length; i++) {
       criteriaQuery.select(root);
       criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(path,orderIds[i]));
     List<E>certificates=super.entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
                    .getResultList();
    map.put(orderIds[i], certificates); This code returns a Map and i want to retrieve a list of all the entities E that have the ids among the orderIds list.